# AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon

Tags: android

Android resource linking failed

```
 Android resource linking failed
    Output:  C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
    C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
    C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v26\values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
    C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:542: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
    C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:542: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
    C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:542: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
    error: failed linking references.

    Command: C:\Users\ramin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\62269942571a2bd8ed5f0b2819ca9a1d\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
            C:\Users\ramin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar\
            --manifest\
            C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
            -o\
            C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
            -R\
            @C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
            --auto-add-overlay\
            --java\
            C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
            --proguard-main-dex\
            C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
            --custom-package\
            com.sell.arkaysell\
            -0\
            apk\
            --output-text-symbols\
            C:\Users\ramin\Desktop\myapp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
            --no-version-vectors
    Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Help me please, tried: Clean project Rebuild Project Invalid Caches / Restart Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: I think you are mission some resources from you colors.xml file... eg: colorError..or can you post in which file are you getting these errors.

Comment: I try to do this but still i get that error

Answer (score 0):

These resources were added in SDK version 28. You need to update your build.gradle file to use `compileSdkVersion 28` (from the error I see you're using 25 instead).